# [Meteor][Reactive Autorun] How to log what caused autorun to run?

Tags: meteor, reactive, autorun

My problem is that some autoruns are fired many times, and i'd like to have a way to quickly check the source.

I wanted to know if something like that was possible :

```
let reactive_var_1 = new ReactiveVar();
let reactive_var_2 = new ReactiveVar();
let reactive_var_3 = new ReactiveVar();
let reactive_var_4 = new ReactiveVar();

Template.test.onCreated(function () {
    console.log('Template.test.onCreated...');
    this.autorun(function () {
        console.log('Template.test.onCreated.autorun...');
        console.log('autorun source is : ');
        console.log(source);

        let do_something_1 = reactive_var_1.get() + 1;
        let do_something_2 = reactive_var_3.get() + 2;
        let do_something_3 = reactive_var_3.get() + 3;
        let do_something_4 = reactive_var_4.get() + 4;
    });
});

Template.test.events({
    'click .something': function () {
        console.log('Someone clicked !!');
        reactive_var_3.set(12);
    }
});
```

Output console should look like this :

```
Template.test.onCreated...
Template.test.onCreated.autorun...
autorun source is : 
undefined
Someone clicked !!
Template.test.onCreated.autorun...
autorun source is : 
'reactive_var_3'
```

This is the **source** function i'm looking for, which could output my **'reactive_var_3'**

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce another cache variable that keeps track of the state of the other variables:

```js
const _cache = {};

const vars = {
  reactive_var_1 : new ReactiveVar();
  reactive_var_2 : new ReactiveVar();
  reactive_var_3 : new ReactiveVar();
  reactive_var_4 : new ReactiveVar();
};
```

In each `autorun` you could check, which of the ractive variables does not match with the cache anymore. The following function provides such a feature:

```js
function diff() {
  const diffs = [];

  Object.keys(vars).forEach( key => {
    const reactiveVar = vars[key];
    const value = reactiveVar.get();

    // if value is different from state
    // it has caused an autorun
    if (_cache[key] !== value) {
      diffs.push(key);
    }

    // update cache
    _cache[key] = value;
  });

  return diffs;
}
```

In your `autorun` you can just call the `diff` methods and get the keys (names) of the variables that caused the tracker to run again:

```js
Template.test.onCreated(function () {
    console.log('Template.test.onCreated...');
    this.autorun(function () {
        console.log('Template.test.onCreated.autorun...');
        console.log('autorun source is : ');

        console.log(diff());

        let do_something_1 = reactive_var_1.get() + 1;
        let do_something_2 = reactive_var_3.get() + 2;
        let do_something_3 = reactive_var_3.get() + 3;
        let do_something_4 = reactive_var_4.get() + 4;
    });
});
```

Note that the cache is immediately updated in the `diff` function. If this limits your use case, you may extract it into a separate function like `updateCache` or something.

Also note, that `_cache` exists outside the template, which can be a problem when using several instances of the same template. You may then switch to another approach and keep the `_cache` and `vars` as local variables within the to the template instance:

```js
Template.test.onCreated(function () {
    console.log('Template.test.onCreated...');

    const _cache = //...
    const vars = //...

    function diff(){ /* ... */ }

    this.autorun(function () {
        console.log('Template.test.onCreated.autorun...');
        console.log('autorun source is : ');

        console.log(diff());

        let do_something_1 = reactive_var_1.get() + 1;
        let do_something_2 = reactive_var_3.get() + 2;
        let do_something_3 = reactive_var_3.get() + 3;
        let do_something_4 = reactive_var_4.get() + 4;
    });
});
```